# Example of misuse of std::memory_order::relaxed in C++ Standard [algorithms.parallel.exec/5 in n4713]

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, relaxed-atomics

One of the examples of misuse of `std::memory_order::relaxed` in C++ Standard:

```
std::atomic<int> x{0};
int a[] = {1,2};
std::for_each(std::execution::par, std::begin(a), std::end(a), [&](int) {
    x.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order::relaxed);
    // spin wait for another iteration to change the value of x
    while (x.load(std::memory_order::relaxed) == 1) { } // incorrect: assumes execution order
});
```

And then it says,

> The above example depends on the order of execution of the iterations, and will not terminate if both iterations are executed sequentially on the same thread of execution.

Questions:

1. The comment says, "incorrect: assumes execution order".  What's the "assumed execution order"?  I miss it.
2. What does the "iterations" refer to in "The above example depends on the order of execution of the iterations"?  Does it mean the iteration in while loop?  Or does it refer to the 
   iteration of `std::for_each`?
3. If the iterations of `std::for_each` are executed in parallel by different threads, isn't it still true that one of the iterations/threads won't exit?  Because `x.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order::relaxed)` is atomic and so one thread will make `x` 1 and another will make `x` 2 and it is impossible to have x == 1 for both thread.   No?

Comment: Re 3.: I think you misread the `while`. It blocks _while_ `x == 1`, not _until_. If both threads eventually read `x == 2` (which they would if the atomics were not relaxed) then everything would be fine.

Comment: @MaxLanghof ah yes my bad.  Thanks!

Comment: Please include section references when quoting the standard (this is from [algorithms.parallel.exec/3]). Also, this has nothing to do with a misuse of `std::memory_order_relaxed` – by which I mean it would even happen with `std::memory_order_seq_cst`, but wrong assumptions regarding concurrent execution in parallel `std::for_each`, as Maxim Egorushkin explained.

Comment: @MaxLanghof What would changing "relaxed" guarantee?

Comment: @curiousguy You're right, my comment is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "incorrect: assumes execution order". What's the "assumed execution order"?

It assumes that the body of the lambda gets executed by multiple threads rather than one. The standard rather says that it *may* execute in parallel.

> What does the "iterations" refer to in "The above example depends on the order of execution of the iterations"?

It probably refers to the execution of the lambda by another thread. But the standard doesn't guarantee that there is another thread. See [execution_policy_tag_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t):

> `parallel_policy` The execution policy type used as a unique type to disambiguate parallel algorithm overloading and indicate that a parallel algorithm's execution may be parallelized. The invocations of element access functions in parallel algorithms invoked with this policy (usually specified as std::execution::par) are **permitted to execute in either the invoking thread or in a thread implicitly created by the library to support parallel algorithm execution. Any such invocations executing in the same thread are indeterminately sequenced with respect to each other.**